# How do I test for page orientation in LaTeX?

Tags: conditionals, landscape

I'm looking for a way to test whether the current orientation of my document is portrait or landscape within LaTeX.

This would be similar to the following test for font size:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\f@size}{10}}{something if 10pt}{something else otherwise}
```

but I haven't been able to get hold of the name of a variable that contains actual orientation (portrait or landscape).

Comment: You could examine the values of the lengths `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`, to see which was larger.  The test?  `\ifdim\paperwidth>\paperheight\relax landscape\else portrait\fi`

Comment: Just tried the suggestion from @StevenB.Segletes and it works flawlessly. Will format it into an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 3):

The following conditional does the job, implementing the comment from Steven B. Segletes while preserving the intended `\ifthenelse{}{}{}` syntax:

```
\ifthenelse{\paperwidth < \paperheight}{portrait}{landscape}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\ifthenelse{\paperwidth < \paperheight}{portrait}{landscape}`

Only works if the whole document is rotated (which was the original question), I'm still to find a way to determine if a single page is rotated

Changing the orientation with `\begin{landscape}` doesn't change any page dimensions. It just rotates the content
A simple test with:

```
\begin{document}

\the\pagewidth \\
\the\pageheight

\begin{landscape}

\the\pagewidth \\
\the\pageheight

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Produces exactly the same on both pages
597.50787pt
845.04684pt

```
\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{\paperwidth < \paperheight}{portrait}{landscape}

\begin{landscape}

\ifthenelse{\paperwidth < \paperheight}{portrait}{landscape}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Shows portrait on both pages